# OpenCL Matrix Multiplication on Radeon HD 7970 and Intel HD 4000 GPUs vs Eigen on CPU

Tags: matlab, opencl, eigen

I am having some problems understanding the outcome of my comparison.

Laptop with i7/intel hd4000 and server with 8Xeon 5400/7970 HDRadeon.

I am multiplying:

```
int M =1024*2, N = 1024*6, P = 1024*2;
    //      N               P      
    //|-----------|   |-----------|
    //|           |   |           |
    //|M          | * |N          |
    //|           |   |           |
    //|-----------|   |-----------|
```

This is the kernel:

```
/*
 * Copyright 1993-2010 NVIDIA Corporation.  All rights reserved.
 *
 * Please refer to the NVIDIA end user license agreement (EULA) associated
 * with this source code for terms and conditions that govern your use of
 * this software. Any use, reproduction, disclosure, or distribution of
 * this software and related documentation outside the terms of the EULA
 * is strictly prohibited.
 *
 */

/* Matrix multiplication: C = A * B.
 * Device code.
 */
#ifndef BLOCK_SIZE
#define BLOCK_SIZE 16
#endif

#define AS(i, j) As[j + i * BLOCK_SIZE]
#define BS(i, j) Bs[j + i * BLOCK_SIZE]

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! Matrix multiplication on the device: C = A * B
//! uiWA is A's width and uiWB is B's width
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
__kernel void
m_m_mul( __global float* A, __global float* B, __global float* C, 
       /*__local float* As, __local float* Bs,*/ int uiWA, int uiWB, int trueLocalSize1)
{

   __local float As[BLOCK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE];
   __local float Bs[BLOCK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE];

    // Block index
    int bx = get_group_id(0);
    int by = get_group_id(1);

    // Thread index
    int tx = get_local_id(0);
    int ty = get_local_id(1);

    // Index of the first sub-matrix of A processed by the block
    int aBegin = uiWA * BLOCK_SIZE * by;

    // Index of the last sub-matrix of A processed by the block
    int aEnd   = aBegin + uiWA - 1;

    // Step size used to iterate through the sub-matrices of A
    int aStep  = BLOCK_SIZE;

    // Index of the first sub-matrix of B processed by the block
    int bBegin = BLOCK_SIZE * bx;

    // Step size used to iterate through the sub-matrices of B
    int bStep  = BLOCK_SIZE * uiWB;

    // Csub is used to store the element of the block sub-matrix
    // that is computed by the thread
    float Csub = 0.0f;

    // Loop over all the sub-matrices of A and B
    // required to compute the block sub-matrix
    for (int a = aBegin, b = bBegin;
             a <= aEnd;
             a += aStep, b += bStep) {

        // Load the matrices from device memory
        // to shared memory; each thread loads
        // one element of each matrix
        AS(ty, tx) = A[a + uiWA * ty + tx];
        BS(ty, tx) = B[b + uiWB * ty + tx];

        // Synchronize to make sure the matrices are loaded
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

        // Multiply the two matrices together;
        // each thread computes one element
        // of the block sub-matrix        
        #pragma unroll
        for (int k = 0; k < BLOCK_SIZE; ++k)
            Csub += AS(ty, k) * BS(k, tx);

        // Synchronize to make sure that the preceding
        // computation is done before loading two new
        // sub-matrices of A and B in the next iteration
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    }

    if (get_global_id(1) < trueLocalSize1)
    // Write the block sub-matrix to device memory;
    // each thread writes one element
    C[get_global_id(1) * get_global_size(0) + get_global_id(0)] = Csub;

}
```

I compare with `Eigen::Matrix<float,-1,-1,Eigen::RowMajor> m4 = m1 * m2`;

On the server:

```
Creating matrices on GPU....... Done [0ms]
Creating matrices on CPU....... Done [0ms]
Filling GPU with random numbers....... Done [19ms]
M3 = M1 * M2... on GPU (Loading Kernels)... Done [240ms]
M3 = M1 * M2... on GPU (3 times)... Done [211ms]
Loading M1, M2 on GPU... Done [93ms]
M4 = M1 * M2 on CPU... Done [7775ms] Error:3.78049e-008
Press any key to continue . . .
Matlab: Elapsed time is 3.010626 seconds.
```

On the Laptop:

```
Creating matrices on GPU....... Done [22ms]
Creating matrices on CPU....... Done [0ms]
Filling GPU with random numbers....... Done [35ms]
M3 = M1 * M2... on GPU (Loading Kernels)... Done [2975ms]
M3 = M1 * M2... on GPU (3 times)... Done [6891ms]
Loading M1, M2 on GPU... Done [80ms]
M4 = M1 * M2 on CPU... Done [5966ms] Error:3.78049e-008
Press any key to continue . . .
Matlab: Elapsed time is 2.310626 seconds.
```

My questions are now.
1) Why are the laptop faster with eigen then the 8 cores of xeon. Could it be that eigen only use one core on both systems and i7 has a higher clockspeed?2.0 vs 2.4?

2) Almost 3 times speed up using Intel HD4000 vs Eigen on labtop, but Matlab takes 2.3sec for the same multiplication. Thats the same as the kernel on HD4000. (Can i do something to get Eigen to run at same speed as Matlab?)

Comment: Can you use a combination of GPU-z and task manager to check which CPU cores/GPU devices each program is using? Sounds like matlab is using all cores and/or GPU but by default your Eigen code is using a single core.

Comment: Interesting theory, i belive that is the case. Wonder if i can enable all cores for Eigen.

Comment: Matlab uses all 8 notes on the server and 4 on the Laptop. Tested on some large matrices, and the server was about 2x faster.

Comment: First, can you show the result of running your kernel on the CPU (I mean with OpenCL not with Eigen)?  That should use all the cores.  Second to see which cores are being used, assuming Windows, start the task manager and got to Performance.  If you run your kernel in OpenCL you should see all cores being used.

Comment: When the kernel is optimized for an GPU, would it make sense to run it on the cpu with opencl? I am more interested in the possible gain from my existing matlab code if moved to a GPU. Therefor i used Eigen for the c++ implementation to get a feeling that its about equal to matlab, which it was. Then i performed the same task on GPU to see what kind of speed up i could get. Enabling MP solved the initial problem of Eigen not using all cores.

Comment: I would just try the kernel on the CPU and see.  You might be surprised by the performance.  Though it still won't be anywhere near as good as the GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html

Enabling OpenMP in visual studio made my code run with 8 cores and reduced speed significant. Running time 80% of matlabs speed.

```
Cores: 8
M: 4096 N:12288 P:4096
Creating matrices on GPU....... Done [0ms]
Creating matrices on CPU....... Done [0ms]
Filling GPU with random numbers....... Done [44ms]
M3 = M1 * M2... on GPU (Loading Kernels)... Done [850ms]
M3 = M1 * M2... on GPU (3 times)... Done [2063ms]
Loading M1, M2 on GPU... Done [355ms]
M4 = M1 * M2 on CPU... Done [22263ms] Error:5.70124e-007
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a race condition? A race condition can cause the performance to be much worse than a single thread.

Comment: I am not sure, but at the end i got 20-30 times speed up using GPU then the 8 cores on the server which i think is fine. I am manly surprised by the poor performance of the intel hd4000 gpu compared to the i7 processor in the laptop.

Comment: The HD4000 in my experience is not very good for OpenCL.  Many of my kernels which run fine on the GPU and CPU won't even run on the HD4000.  But one great thing you can do with OpenCL is run on multiple devices at once.  I do this in ray tracing.  You can split the matrix multiply between the CPU and the HD4000.  You just create two threads and a separate context for each thread.  Then you have to distribute the load between each device proportional to their "speed".  You can do the same on the server but since the GPU is so much faster than the CPU it won't decrease the time much.